Mail sent by an Azure function has the wrong encoding
I've created an in-process Azure function (v4 using .Net 6) that sends a bunch of Emails.
I'm using a middleware service for sending Mail that uses MailKit 3.1.0
I start by creating a simple mimeKit message (Where the messageBody is basic HTML-code <p>Åäö</p>)
public MimeKit.MimeMessage CreateMessage(bool htmlBody = true, string messageBody, string 
messageSubject, List<string> mailRecipients, string mailSender)
{
    var mailKitMessage = new MimeKit.MimeMessage();
    mailKitMessage.From.Add(MimeKit.InternetAddress.Parse(mailSender));
    mailKitMessage.To.AddRange(mailRecipients.Select(address => MimeKit.InternetAddress.Parse(address)));
    mailKitMessage.Subject = messageSubject;
    var bodyBuilder = new MimeKit.BodyBuilder();

    if (htmlBody)
    {
        bodyBuilder.HtmlBody = $"<div style=\"font-family: helvetica; font-size: 10px;\">{messageBody}</div>";
    }
    else
    {
        bodyBuilder.TextBody = messageBody;
    }

    mailKitMessage.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();
    return mailKitMessage;
}

Then calling the following MailKit.
public async Task SendAsync(MimeKit.MimeMessage message)
{
    using (var smtpClient = new MailKit.Net.Smtp.SmtpClient())
    {
        await smtpClient.ConnectAsync(this.SmtpHost, this.PortNumber, MailKit.Security.SecureSocketOptions.StartTls).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await smtpClient.AuthenticateAsync(this.GetDomainSpecificMailjetCredentials(message.Sender)).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await smtpClient.SendAsync(message).ConfigureAwait(false);
        await smtpClient.DisconnectAsync(true).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }
}

This works great when running stuff through a VM or locally, but when i upload it to Azure all Scandinavian special characters ('Å', 'Ä', 'Ö', 'Ø')  are turned into ���.
I know that this happens when your application is using latin1 but trying to show it as UTF-8. So i tried fixing this by overloading the:
smtpClient.AuthenticateAsync(this.GetDomainSpecificMailjetCredentials(message.Sender));

to
smtpClient.AuthenticateAsync(Encoding.Default, this.GetDomainSpecificMailjetCredentials(message.Sender));

In hopes it'd stop trying to convert it, but this didn't work.
So my first question is why is My Azure function sending email encoded as Latin1 when normal Appservices/local development works fine using the same code, second of all how do i force my Azure Functions to encode the mail message correctly? Is there a setting somewhere?

You can try to modify your CreateMessage method to explicitly set the character encoding to UTF-8. By explicitly specifying UTF-8 encoding in the CreateMessage method, you ensure that the email content is encoded correctly regardless of the environment in which your Azure Function is running.
mailKitMessage.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody(Encoding.UTF8);

